# How host different content for a single domain and subdomain firebase

Tags: firebase, deployment, configuration, hosting

I have an site, let's call it 'foo'.

I wanna have three contents.

1 site will be the landing page.
1 site will be contentA.
1 site will be contentB.

The domains must be:

```
foo.com (with landingpage)
content1.foo.com (with content1)
content2.foo.com (with content2)
```

All sites are a big project on firebase.
But when i deploy i cannot set target to subdomain (which is already configured).
How can configure this setup ? I want 3 contents on same domain, all hosted by firebase.